# How can I write only a specific elements of the sequences, that I downloaded using Entrez.efetch, to the file (id and sequence itself)

Tags: biopython

I'm still a beginner at this. I downloaded 20 sequences from NCBI and my task is to align them with themselves, but I need to separate the data, that I got using **Entrez.efetch**, so I could use it for alignment and I couldn't write the only specific elements (id and sequence) to the file, that I created.

It seems very difficult to get the elements from output because I get dictionaries in the list. So I am stuck here, maybe someone could give me some advice, all help would be appreciated. Here is my code and output: list of ids and (first 5 lines) that I get.

```
!pip install biopython
import biopython as Bio
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO
Entrez.email = "amasla1121@gmail.com"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term="33175[BioProject] OR 33317[BioProject] ", retmode="fasta",idtype="acc")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
idpanaudot = record["IdList"]
print(idpanaudot)
for i in idpanaudot:
  handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=i, rettype="fasta", retmode="xml",idtype="acc")
  read = Entrez.read(handle)
  print(read)
  fout = open('bioinfo2_sekos.fasta','w')
  fout.write(str(read) +'\n')
  fout.close
*THE OUTPUT*
['NR_174239.1', 'NR_172610.1', 'NR_171531.1', 'NR_171505.1', 'NR_171466.1', 'NR_171462.1', 'NR_171459.1', 'NR_171396.1', 'NR_171395.1', 'NR_171394.1', 'NR_170538.1', 'NR_170493.1', 'NR_170423.1', 'NR_170422.1', 'NR_170421.1', 'NR_170409.1', 'NR_170397.1', 'NR_169483.1', 'NR_169479.1', 'NR_169460.1']
[{'TSeq_seqtype': StringElement('', attributes={'value': 'nucleotide'}), 'TSeq_accver': 'NR_174239.1', 'TSeq_sid': 'gnl|REF_SSU16S|MG437235:1-1495', 'TSeq_taxid': '2320269', 'TSeq_orgname': 'Altericroceibacterium spongiae', 'TSeq_defline': 'Altericroceibacterium spongiae strain HN-Y73 16S ribosomal RNA, complete sequence', 'TSeq_length': '1492', 'TSeq_sequence': 'AAACTTGAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCATGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAACGAAGTCTTCGGACTTAGTGGCGCACGGGTGCGTAACGCGTGGGAACCTGCCCTTAGGTTCGGAATAACAGTTAGAAATGACTGCTAATACCGGATAATGTCTTCGGACCAAAGATTTATCGCCTTTGGATGGGCCCGCGTTAGATTAGGTAGTTGGTGGGGTAAAGGCCTACCAAGCCGACGATCTATAGCTGGTCTGAGAGGATGATCAGCCACACTGGGACTGAGACACGGCCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGGGAAACCCTGATCCAGCAATGCCGCGTGAGTGATGAAGGCCTTAGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTACCAGGGATGATAATGACAGTACCTGGAGAATAAGCTCCGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGGAGCTAGCGTTGTTCGGAATTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGCGTAGGCGGTTTACCAAGTCAGGGGTGAAATCCCGGGGCTCAACCCCGGAACTGCCCTTGAAACTGGTAGACTAGAATCCTGGAGAGGCGAGTGGAATTCCGAGTGTAGAGGTGAAATTCGTAGATATTCGGAAGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTCGCTGGACAGGTATTGACGCTGAGGTGCGAAAGTGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACACCGTAAACGATGATAACTAGCTGTCCGGGTTCATGGAACTTGGGTGGCGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGTTATCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGTCGCAAGATTAAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCTGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGCAGAACCTTACCAGCGTTTGACATCCCGATTTTGGTTTTCAGAGATGGATTCCTTCAGTTCGGCTGGATCGGTGACAGGTGCTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTCATCCTTAGTTGCCATCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGAAACTGCCGGTGATAAGCCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAGTCCTCATGGCCCTTACACGCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGCGGTGACAGTGGGCAGCTAACCCGCGAGGGCAAGCTAATCTCCAAAAACCGTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTTCTCTGCAACTCGAGAGCATGAAGGCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCAGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCATGGGAGTTGGTTTCACCCGAAGGCGCTGCGTTAACCCGCAAGGGAGACAGGCGACCACGGTGGGATCAGCGACTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAGCCGTAGGGGAACCTGCGGCTGGATCACCTCCTTTCTA'}]
[{'TSeq_seqtype': StringElement('', attributes={'value': 'nucleotide'}), 'TSeq_accver': 'NR_172610.1', 'TSeq_sid': 'gnl|REF_SSU16S|MT311247:1-1576', 'TSeq_taxid': '2786940', 'TSeq_orgname': 'Marmoreocelis xerophila', 'TSeq_defline': 'Marmoreocelis xerophila strain CATCB5 16S ribosomal RNA, partial sequence', 'TSeq_length': '1144', 'TSeq_sequence': 'GGGGAATTTTCCGCAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGACGGAGCAAGACCGCGTGAGGGAGGAAGGCTCTTGGGTTGTAAACCTCTTTTCTCAGGGAAGAACACAATGACGGTACCTGAGGAATCAGCCTCGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGAGGCAAGCGTTATCCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCCGTAGGTGGTCATGTAAGTCGGTCGTCAAAGCACAGGGCTTAACCCTGTAATGGCGGTGGAAACTGCACGACTAGAGAGAGGTAGGGGTAGAGGGAATTCCCAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTGGGAAGAACATCGGTGGCGAAAGCGCTCTACTGGACCTCATCTGACGCTGATGGACGAAAGCTAGGGGAGCGAATGGGATTAGATACCCCAGTAGTCCTAGCCGTAAACGATGGATACTAGATGTTGTCTGTATCGACCCAGACAGTGTCGTAGCTAACGCGTTAAGTATCCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGCACGCAAGTGTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGTATGTGGTTTAATTCGATGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGGCTTGACATGTCCGGAATCGAGGGGAAACTTTCGAGTGCCTACGGGAGCCGGAACACAGGTGGTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTCGTCCTTAGTTACCAGCATTGAGTTGGGCACTCTGGGGAGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAGTCAGTATGCCCCTTACGTCCTGGGCGACACACGTACTACAATGCTGCGGACAAAGGGCAGCGAACACGCGAGTGCCAGCTAATCCCATAAACCGTGGCTCAGTTCAGATCGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCGTGAAGGAGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCCGGTCAGCATACGGCGGTGAATTCGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCATGGGAGCTGTTTAGCCCGAAGTCGTTACCCTAACCTTTTAGGAGGGGGACGCCGAAGGCTGGGCTGGTGACTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAGCCGTACCGGAAGGTGT'}]
[{'TSeq_seqtype': StringElement('', attributes={'value': 'nucleotide'}), 'TSeq_accver': 'NR_171531.1', 'TSeq_sid': 'gnl|REF_SSU16S|MH551483:1-1514', 'TSeq_taxid': '2321395', 'TSeq_orgname': 'Siminovitchia acidinfaciens', 'TSeq_defline': 'Siminovitchia acidinfaciens strain 3-2-2 16S ribosomal RNA, partial sequence', 'TSeq_length': '1514', 'TSeq_sequence': 'AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGGACGAACGCTGGCGGCGTGCCTAATACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGATGAAGAGGAGCTTGCTCCTTGGATTCAGCGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAACACGTGGGCAACCTGCCTGTAAGACTGGGATAACTCCGGGAAACCGGGGCTAATACCGGATAACTTCTTTTCTCGCATGGGAAGAGGTTGAAAGACGGTTTTGCTGTCACTTACAGATGGGCCCGCGGCGCATTAGCTAGTTGGTGGGGTAACGGCCTACCAAGGCGACGATGCGTAGCCGACCTGAGAGGGTGATCGGCCACACTGGGACTGAGACACGGCCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCCGCAATGGACGAAAGTCTGACGGAGCAACGCCGCGTGAGTGACGAAGGCCTTCGGGTCGTAAAACTCTGTTATCAGGGAAGAACAAGCATCATTTAACTGATGGTGCCTTGACGGTACCTGACCAGAAAGCCACGGCTAACTACGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGTAGGTGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGCGCAGGCGGCTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGGCTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGAAGAGCGGAATTCCACGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATGTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCTCTTTGGTCTGTAACTGACGCTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGAGAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTATTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGGGGGTTTCCGCCCCTTAGTGCTGCAGCAAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCCGCTGACCGGTGCAGAGATGTGCCTTTCCCTTCGGGGACAGCGGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAGAGGGCAGCGAGACCGCGAGGTTCAGCGAATCCCTTAAAACCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACCCTTCTGGGAGCCAGCCGCCGAAGGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAGCCGTA'}]
[{'TSeq_seqtype': StringElement('', attributes={'value': 'nucleotide'}), 'TSeq_accver': 'NR_171505.1', 'TSeq_sid': 'gnl|REF_SSU16S|MH090938:1-1515', 'TSeq_taxid': '2303987', 'TSeq_orgname': 'Motilimonas pumila', 'TSeq_defline': 'Motilimonas pumila strain PLHSC7-2 16S ribosomal RNA, partial sequence', 'TSeq_length': '1515', 'TSeq_sequence': 'TCTAGAGATTAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATTGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCTTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGTAACATTTCTAGCTTGCTAGAAGATGACGAGCGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAATGCTTGGGTATCTGCCTTGAGGTGGGGGACAACAGTTGGAAACGACTGCTAATACCGCATAATCTCTACGGAGCAAAGAGGGGGACCTTCGGGCCTCTCGCCACAAGATGAACCCAAGTGGGATTAGCTAGTTGGTAAGGTAACGGCTTACCAAGGCGACGATCCCTAGCTGGTCTGAGAGGATGACCAGCCACACTGGAACTGAGACACGGTCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGGGGAATATTGCACAATGGGGGAAACCCTGATGCAGCCATGCCGCGTGTGTGAAGAAGGCCTTCGGGTTGTAAAGCACTTTCAGTTGTGAGGAAAGGTTAGTAGTTAATAACTGCTAGCTGTGACGTTAGCAACAGAAGAAGCACCGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGGTGCGAGCGTTAATCGGAATTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGTGTAGGTGGCTTGTTAAGCCAGATGTGAAAGCCCCGGGCTCAACCTGGGAACTGCATTTGGAACTGGCAGGCTAGAGTTTTGTAGAGGGTGGTAGAATTTCAGGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATCTGAAGGAATACCGGTGGCGAAGGCGACCACCTGGACAGAAACTGACACTCAGACGCGAAGGCGTGGGTAGCAAACGGGATTAGATACCCCGGTAGTCCACGCAGTAAACGATGTCTATTAGGAGTTTGGTATCTTGTATACTGGGCTCCAAAGCTAACGCATTAAATAGACCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGTTAAAACTCAAATGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGATGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCTACTCTTGACATCCACGGAATTTTTCAGAGATGAATTAGTGCCTTCGGGAACCGTGAGACAGGTGCTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTTGTGAAATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCCTATCCTTAGTTGCCAGCGATTCGGTCGGGAACTCTAGGGAGACTGCCGGTGATAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGACGACGTCAAGTCATCATGGCCCTTACGAGTAGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGCGGATACAAAGGGCAGCTAACTTGCGAGAGTGTGCGAATCCCAAAAAGTCCGTCGTAGTCCGGATTGGAGTCTGCAACTCGACTCCATGAAGTCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGTGGATCAGAATGCCGTGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCATGGGAGTGGGCTGCAAAAGAAGTAGGTAGTTTAACCTTCGGGAGGACGCTTACCACTTTGTGGTTCATGACTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAGCCGTAA'}]
[{'TSeq_seqtype': StringElement('', attributes={'value': 'nucleotide'}), 'TSeq_accver': 'NR_171466.1', 'TSeq_sid': 'gnl|REF_SSU16S|LC436604:1-1421', 'TSeq_taxid': '2493111', 'TSeq_orgname': 'Lacticaseibacillus hulanensis', 'TSeq_defline': 'Lacticaseibacillus hulanensis strain ZW163 16S ribosomal RNA, partial sequence', 'TSeq_length': '1421', 'TSeq_sequence': 'AATGAACGGAGTGCTTGCACGAAGTGATTTAAGAGCGGTGAGTGGCGGATGGGTGAGTAACACGTGGGTAACCTGCCTTCTAGCAGGGGATAACATCTGGAAACAGGTGCTAATACCGTATAAATCTCAAAACCGCATGGTTTTGAGCTGAAAGGCGGCTTCGGCTGTCACTAGAAGATGGACCCGCGGTGCATTAGTTAGTTGGTGAGGTAAAGGCCCACCAAGACTGTGATGCATAGCCGAACTGAGAGGTTGATCGGCCACATTGGGACTGAGACACGGCCCAAACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCCACAATGGACGAAAGTCTGATGGAGCAACGCCGCGTGAGTGAAGAAGGTTTTCGGATCGTAAAGCTCTGTTGTTGGAGAAGAACACTAGTGAGAGTAACTGTTCATTAGTTGACGGTATCCAACCAGAAAGCCACGGCTAACTACGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGTAGGTGGCGAGCGTTATCCGGATTTATTGGGCGTAAAGCGAGCGCAGGCGGTTTTTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCCCGGCTCAACCGGGGAAGTGCATCGGAAACTGGGAAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGACAGTGGAACTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATATGGAAGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCTGTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACGCTGAGGCTCGAAAGCATGGGTAGCGAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCATGCCGTAAACGATGAATACTAAGTGTTGGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTCAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGTATTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGACCGCAAGGTTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCTTCTGCCAACCCAAGAGATTGGGCGTTCCCTTCGGGGACAGAATGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTATGACTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAGTAAGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGACGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGCCGGTACAACGAGTCGCCAACCCGCGAGGGTGCGCTAATCTCTTAAAGCCGGTCTCAGTTCGGACTGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCACGAAGTCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCATGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGCCGGTGGGGTAACCCTTTTAGGGAGCTAGCCGTCTA'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO

Entrez.email = "amasla1121@gmail.com"
Entrez.api_key = #Here should be your API key

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term="33175[BioProject] OR 33317[BioProject] ", retmode="fasta", idtype="acc")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
idpanaudot = record["IdList"]
with open("test.fas", "w") as file:
    for id in idpanaudot:
        fasta_rec = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=id, rettype="fasta", retmode="text", idtype="acc").read()
        file.write(fasta_rec)
```

The first three records in my test.fas:

```
>NR_174239.1 Altericroceibacterium spongiae strain HN-Y73 16S ribosomal RNA, complete sequence
AAACTTGAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCATGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAACGAA
GTCTTCGGACTTAGTGGCGCACGGGTGCGTAACGCGTGGGAACCTGCCCTTAGGTTCGGAATAACAGTTA
GAAATGACTGCTAATACCGGATAATGTCTTCGGACCAAAGATTTATCGCCTTTGGATGGGCCCGCGTTAG
ATTAGGTAGTTGGTGGGGTAAAGGCCTACCAAGCCGACGATCTATAGCTGGTCTGAGAGGATGATCAGCC
ACACTGGGACTGAGACACGGCCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGGGAA
ACCCTGATCCAGCAATGCCGCGTGAGTGATGAAGGCCTTAGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTACCAGGGATGAT
AATGACAGTACCTGGAGAATAAGCTCCGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGGAGCTA
GCGTTGTTCGGAATTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGCGTAGGCGGTTTACCAAGTCAGGGGTGAAATCCCGGGG
CTCAACCCCGGAACTGCCCTTGAAACTGGTAGACTAGAATCCTGGAGAGGCGAGTGGAATTCCGAGTGTA
GAGGTGAAATTCGTAGATATTCGGAAGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTCGCTGGACAGGTATTGACGCT
GAGGTGCGAAAGTGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACACCGTAAACGATGATAACT
AGCTGTCCGGGTTCATGGAACTTGGGTGGCGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGTTATCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGTC
GCAAGATTAAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCTGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGC
AACGCGCAGAACCTTACCAGCGTTTGACATCCCGATTTTGGTTTTCAGAGATGGATTCCTTCAGTTCGGC
TGGATCGGTGACAGGTGCTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAAC
GAGCGCAACCCTCATCCTTAGTTGCCATCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGAAACTGCCGGTGATAAGCCG
GAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAGTCCTCATGGCCCTTACACGCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGCG
GTGACAGTGGGCAGCTAACCCGCGAGGGCAAGCTAATCTCCAAAAACCGTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTTCTCT
GCAACTCGAGAGCATGAAGGCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCA
GGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCATGGGAGTTGGTTTCACCCGAAGGCGCTGCGTTAACCCGCAAG
GGAGACAGGCGACCACGGTGGGATCAGCGACTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAGCCGTAGGGGAACCTG
CGGCTGGATCACCTCCTTTCTA

>NR_172610.1 Marmoreocelis xerophila strain CATCB5 16S ribosomal RNA, partial sequence
GGGGAATTTTCCGCAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGACGGAGCAAGACCGCGTGAGGGAGGAAGGCTCTTGGGTTG
TAAACCTCTTTTCTCAGGGAAGAACACAATGACGGTACCTGAGGAATCAGCCTCGGCTAACTCCGTGCCA
GCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGAGGCAAGCGTTATCCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCCGTAGGTGGTC
ATGTAAGTCGGTCGTCAAAGCACAGGGCTTAACCCTGTAATGGCGGTGGAAACTGCACGACTAGAGAGAG
GTAGGGGTAGAGGGAATTCCCAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTGGGAAGAACATCGGTGGCGAAA
GCGCTCTACTGGACCTCATCTGACGCTGATGGACGAAAGCTAGGGGAGCGAATGGGATTAGATACCCCAG
TAGTCCTAGCCGTAAACGATGGATACTAGATGTTGTCTGTATCGACCCAGACAGTGTCGTAGCTAACGCG
TTAAGTATCCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGCACGCAAGTGTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAG
CGGTGGAGTATGTGGTTTAATTCGATGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGGCTTGACATGTCCGGAATCGA
GGGGAAACTTTCGAGTGCCTACGGGAGCCGGAACACAGGTGGTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTG
AGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTCGTCCTTAGTTACCAGCATTGAGTTGGGCACTCT
GGGGAGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAGTCAGTATGCCCCTTACGTCCTG
GGCGACACACGTACTACAATGCTGCGGACAAAGGGCAGCGAACACGCGAGTGCCAGCTAATCCCATAAAC
CGTGGCTCAGTTCAGATCGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCGTGAAGGAGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCCGGTCA
GCATACGGCGGTGAATTCGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCATGGGAGCTGTTTAGCCC
GAAGTCGTTACCCTAACCTTTTAGGAGGGGGACGCCGAAGGCTGGGCTGGTGACTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAA
CAAGGTAGCCGTACCGGAAGGTGT

>NR_171531.1 Siminovitchia acidinfaciens strain 3-2-2 16S ribosomal RNA, partial sequence
AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGGACGAACGCTGGCGGCGTGCCTAATACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGATGAAGAG
GAGCTTGCTCCTTGGATTCAGCGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAACACGTGGGCAACCTGCCTGTAAGACTGGGAT
AACTCCGGGAAACCGGGGCTAATACCGGATAACTTCTTTTCTCGCATGGGAAGAGGTTGAAAGACGGTTT
TGCTGTCACTTACAGATGGGCCCGCGGCGCATTAGCTAGTTGGTGGGGTAACGGCCTACCAAGGCGACGA
TGCGTAGCCGACCTGAGAGGGTGATCGGCCACACTGGGACTGAGACACGGCCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGC
AGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCCGCAATGGACGAAAGTCTGACGGAGCAACGCCGCGTGAGTGACGAAGGCCTTC
GGGTCGTAAAACTCTGTTATCAGGGAAGAACAAGCATCATTTAACTGATGGTGCCTTGACGGTACCTGAC
CAGAAAGCCACGGCTAACTACGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGTAGGTGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGAATTA
TTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGCGCAGGCGGCTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGT
CATTGGAAACTGGGAGGCTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGAAGAGCGGAATTCCACGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAG
AGATGTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCTCTTTGGTCTGTAACTGACGCTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTG
GGGAGAGAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTATTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGGGGGTTT
CCGCCCCTTAGTGCTGCAGCAAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTC
AAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTT
ACCAGGTCTTGACATCCCGCTGACCGGTGCAGAGATGTGCCTTTCCCTTCGGGGACAGCGGTGACAGGTG
GTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATC
TTAGTTGCCAGCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGA
CGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAGAGGGCAGCGA
GACCGCGAGGTTCAGCGAATCCCTTAAAACCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCATG
AAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCG
CCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACCCTTCTGGGAGCCAGCCGCCGAA
GGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAGCCGTA
```